# Automatically redirects from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: http, https

I’ve recently bought an HTTPS licence for my website, and on all browsers, all devices, all operating systems, it always redirects to http. The only exception is when you manually type https in the header.

Is there any programming, configuration or file I need to add to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your Manage SSL section of your account that it is properly configured?

Comment: I need some more info about you website. Do you use Wordpress? Do you have access to the website files?

Comment: @matthijsknigge I don’t use Wordpress. I use a domain with cPanel and I have total access to all website files.

Comment: @DarkVeneno I think is it just a redirection issue. Everything works fine, when you call https manually, right ?

Comment: @Gowthamraj Vungarala Yes it works fine, but I want to set it up automatically :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Log into your host's cPanel.
2. Scroll down to the "Security" section and click "SSL/TLS."
3. You are now in the "SSL/TLS Manager" home. Click "Private Keys (KEY)" to create a new private key.
4. You will be redirected to a page to "Generate, Paste or Upload a new "Private Key." Select "2048-bit" in the "Key Size" dropdown, and click "Generate."
5. The new private key will be generated, and you will get a confirmation screen
6. If you go back to the "Private Keys" home, you will see your new key listed
7. Go back to the "SSL/TLS Manager" home. Click "Certificate Signing Requests (CSR)" to create a new certificate request.
8. You will now be presented with the "Generate Service Request" form. Select the previously created private key and fill in the fields. Answer all of the questions correctly (they will be public in your signed certificate!), paying special attention to the "Domains" section, which should exactly match the domain name for which you are requesting the HTTPS certificate. Include the top-level domain only (example.com); the CA will usually add the www subdomain as well (i.e. www.example.com). When finished, click the "Generate" button.
9. The new CSR will be generated, and you will get a confirmation screen
10. If you go back to the "Certificate Signing Request" home, you will see your new CSR listed